# ThreeJS ExtrudeGeometry HOLE from points

Tags: javascript, three.js

Gutentag, guys!

I am trying to make a hole in my ExtrudeGeometry but it does not work.

My code looks like this:

```
        var shape = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(drawShape(), options), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x593788}))

        function drawShape() {

        // create a basic shape
            var shape = new THREE.Shape();

            shape.moveTo(10, 10);
            shape.lineTo(10, 40);
            shape.lineTo(30, 40);
            shape.lineTo(30, 10);
            shape.lineTo(10, 10);

            var hole1 = new THREE.Path();
            hole1.moveTo(12,15);
            hole1.lineTo(15,16);
            hole1.lineTo(16,16);
            hole1.lineTo(16,15);
            hole1.lineTo(12,15);
            shape.holes.push(hole1);

            return shape;
        }
```

What I am getting is a plain shape figure with no hole

(drew a white hole with Clipping Tool to show where it should be) --->
[image: The Extrude Geometry figure with no hole]

May I ask why is this happening?

Because when I add absellipse or absarc - the hole works fine.

```
        var hole2 = new THREE.Path();
        hole2.absellipse(23, 24, 2, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        shape.holes.push(hole2);
```

[image: Hole]

Is it impossible to push holes made from line points instead of ellipse or arc?

If you have any idea why this does not work or how to fix it, please help.

Comment: Isn't there a hole in the first picture?

Comment: @Mugen87 - I drew it with the clippingTool just to show where it should be.

Comment: I've create a demo with your shape and I'm unable to reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/6153/

Comment: Problem solved? ;)

Comment: @Mugen87 Yes, sorry for the late response. Seems to be working this way, thanks! :)